# Баг при спавне объектов UNITY

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет, столкнулся с такой проблемой:

У меня есть объект (с названием Content), в котором стоит компонент Grid Layout Group и префаб который через скрипт я создаю как дочерний объект content'a.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прикрепил скриншот content'a и то, как выглядит префаб если добавить его в editore.
Вот такую картину я наблюдаю когда создаю объекты через скрипт(первый объект в content'e был добавлен в editor'e)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если в рантайме в ручную в Content перетащить префаб, то он встанет как нужно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот такой у меня код создания перфабов:

```
    private IEnumerator getInfoTopUsers()
    {
        loadBar.SetActive(true);
        UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(link + $"?type=getTop&user_id={user_id}");
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        if (request.isDone)
        {
      
            dataInfoTopUsers data = JsonUtility.FromJson<dataInfoTopUsers>(request.downloadHandler.text);
            int mesto = 1;
            foreach(Users us in data.users)
            {
                GameObject obg = Instantiate(prefabBlock);
                obg.transform.SetParent(parrent.transform);
                blockController bc = obg.GetComponent<blockController>();
                bc.name.text = us.name;
                bc.score.text = us.value;
                bc.mesto.text = mesto.ToString();
                if(us.user_id == int.Parse(user_id))
                {

                    bc.serRedText();
                }
                mesto++;
            }
            loadBar.SetActive(false);
            leaderPanel.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
```

Скрипт BlockController имеет в себе такой код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class blockController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text mesto;
    public Text name;
    public Text score;

    public void serRedText()
    {
        Image image = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Image>();
        image.color = new Color(250/255.0f, 201/255.0f, 89/255.0f,255 / 255.0f);
    }
}
```

В чём может быть причина этого?

Comment: `В чём может быть причина этого?` Здесь - что-то не работает? Надо догадаться, что именно? Исправьте заголовок и текст поста так, чтобы они отражали реальную проблему. А то здесь 99% вопросов будут одинаковые.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос задан ужасно, нужно додуматься до сути проблемы вглядываясь в скрин.

Ваша проблема в том что вы спавните префаб на сцене, а затем меняете родителя на объект канваса в результате чего он не тех размеров.

При смене родителя размер, как и локальный поворос с позицией пересчитывается, что бы оставаться прежнем, то есть если задать объекту с скейлом 1 родителя с скейлом 0.5, его размер пересчитается на 2, что бы остаться прежним.

Просто указывайте родителя вторым аргументом инстантиейта.

```
Instantiate(prefabBlock, parrent.transform);
```

И нет это не баг.